# Uninstall Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

So recently I downloaded the most recent ubuntu iso for installation alongside my Windows 8.1. Everything went really smoothly with no errors or hiccups during installation. The only thing is I've decided that I just wanna go back to using Windows 8.1. I haven't a clue how to uninstall ubuntu now. I was going to use the windows installer but there wasn't one available, however fund this latest iso which provided a much improved installer which as I said made things go a lot better.

Has anyone any idea how to uninstall it as I tried the DVD I burnt the iso to and all it gives me the option of is reinstalling ubuntu, there is no option to uninstall once I've installed.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: 12.10 is recent?! More like end of life ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why would an operating system need an uninstall option? You uninstall an operating system by installing another one over the current one.

Or by starting a 2nd operating system and use their version of gParted and delete the partitions the operating system is on that needs removing.

To clear a disc from all operating systems you could install gParted, unmount all the discs and delete the partitions until you have 1 big "unallocated" space. Booting will then result in a "no operating systems found" error message.

Comment: Good point :D  ...